How to install Windows store on Windows LTSB 1607 14393.7336?
I have Windows LTSB version 1607  compilation 14393.7336
I receive errors when I try to install nuget or Microsoft store apps or Microsoft package manager or ui.xaml
error should be

App installation failed with error message: A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied. (0x80073cfd)

or

error is Invoke WebRequest : Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.

I edited all web.config with this lines
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>

I add it at the end of config file
or
cant run this command
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/PackageManagement/1.4.8.1' -OutFile $env:temp\nuget.zip

or
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PackageSource PSGallery
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
Get-PackageSource : Unable to find package source 'PSGallery'. Use Get-PackageSource to see all available pack
sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PackageSource PSGallery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...etPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-Packag
   , Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SourceNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageSource

I do not have net framework runtime 4.8 installed.
I have net framework SDK 4.8 installed.
I have Microsoft store installed and i can login to my account and see favourites, but i cannot download anything from store ever shows to me error Code:
0x80040154

I have on download quee  Microsoft store and package install manager. It doesn't update with error code:
0x80040154

All times it has error on acquire license.
Can't run some appxbundle packages and other runs and half install or no install at all.
I cannot install msxi files and msxi is not assocciated with any installer.
I want to install store and package manager and nuget and psstore powershell scripts.
Or need how to guide on how to update to latest Windows 10.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Mainstream support for Windows 10 2016 LTSB ended Oct 12, 2021. You consider upgrading to the current Windows 10.

.NET Framework cannot be installed on Windows 10 1607. You will want to upgrade to a supported LTSB release in order to resolve your problem

edited read it now

If what your attempting to install requires .NET Gramework 4.8 then it cannot be installed on 1607. Consider upgrading to a supported version of Windows 10 LTSB
